# How free can I be in the code in an object invariant?

Tags: .net-4.0, code-contracts, visual-studio-2010, invariants

I'm trying to demonstrate invariants in Code Contracts, and I thought I'd give an example of a sorted list of strings. It maintains an array internally, with spare space for additions etc - just like `List<T>`, basically. When it needs to add an item, it inserts it into the array, etc. I figured I had three invariants:

- The count must be sensible: non-negative and at most as big as the buffer size
- Everything in the unused part of the buffer should be null
- Each item in the used part of the buffer should be at least as "big" as the item before it

Now, I've tried to implement that in this way:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    Contract.Invariant(count >= 0 && count <= buffer.Length);
    for (int i = count; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        Contract.Invariant(buffer[i] == null);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        Contract.Invariant(string.Compare(buffer[i], buffer[i - 1]) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `ccrewrite` is messing up the loops.

The user documentation says that the method should just be a series of calls to `Contract.Invariant`. Do I really have to rewrite the code as something like this?

```
Contract.Invariant(count >= 0 && count <= buffer.Length);
Contract.Invariant(Contract.ForAll
    (count, buffer.Length, i => buffer[i] == null));
Contract.Invariant(Contract.ForAll
    (1, count, i => string.Compare(buffer[i], buffer[i - 1]) >= 0));
```

That's somewhat ugly, although it does work. (It's much better than my previous attempt, mind you.)

Are my expectations unreasonable? Are my invariants unreasonable?

(Also asked as a [question in the Code Contracts forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/733c6bc5-6781-4137-a039-ec24c1953f0a). I'll add any relevant answers here myself.)

Comment: Apparently, you cannot be as free as the loop unrolls.  /rimshot

Comment: The bizarre thing is that the *first* loop is okay... but the second isn't. It may turn out to be a bug in ccrewrite, of course.

Comment: (I suspect it's capturing all the code before the call to Contract.Invariant...)

Comment: Jon, ForAll is [a,b) so it should be ForAll(1, count, ...), not count-1

Comment: Doh, yes. Clearly not thinking straight tonight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the (preliminary) MSDN pages it looks like the Contract.ForAll member could help you with the 2 range contracts. The documentation isn't very explicit about its function though.

```
//untested
Contract.Invariant(Contract.ForAll(count, buffer.Length, i => buffer[i] == null));
Contract.Invariant(Contract.ForAll(1, count, 
    i => string.Compare(buffer[i], buffer[i - 1]) >= 0));
```

Comment: I could use ForAll for the first one (if that's allowed in invariants) but the second one needs two elements at a time, which is somewhat trickier.

Comment: There are two version, one is integer-range based and takes a Predicate<int>. I added a sample of how it could work.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Henk - it's definitely looking better than it did. I've used buffer.Skip() with the normal ForAll for the first one, but we're clearly thinking alike for the second :)

Comment: Actually, now I look at it, I think I like your version better all round, as it's closer to the initial code. Editing again. I won't accept the answer *just yet* as I'd still like to hear whether it's expected that my initial code won't work.

Comment: I found in an older posting that Contract.ForAll was not yet supported (static) last april: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/94ec2bce-61b5-463c-a1b6-22c22a42e67f

Comment: Fortunately that doesn't affect me yet as I don't have VSTS :)

Answer (score 3):

(I'm going to accept Henk's answer, but I think it's worth adding this.)

The question has now been answered on the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/733c6bc5-6781-4137-a039-ec24c1953f0a), and the upshot is that the first form *isn't* expected to work. Invariants really, really need to be a series of calls to `Contract.Invariant`, and that's all.

This makes it more feasible for the static checker to understand the invariant and enforce it.

This restriction can be circumvented by simply putting all the logic into a different member, e.g. an `IsValid` property, and then calling:

```
Contract.Invariant(IsValid);
```

That would no doubt mess up the static checker, but in some cases it may be a useful alternative in some cases.

Comment: Pretty much what I suggested. I would adopt this as an "effective" pattern when using .Net Code Contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the designers reinventing the wheel a bit?

What was wrong with the [good old](http://www.state-machine.com/writings/samek0308.pdf)

```
bool Invariant() const; // in C++, mimicking Eiffel
```

?

Now in C# we don't have const, but why can't you just define an `Invariant` function

```
private bool Invariant()
{
  // All the logic, function returns true if object is valid i.e. function
  // simply will never return false, in the absence of a bug
}
// Good old invariant in C#, no special attributes, just a function
```

and then just use the Code Contracts in terms of that function?

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    Contract.Invariant(Invariant() == true);
}
```

Maybe I'm writing nonsense, but even in that case it will have some didactic value when everybody tells me wrong.

Comment: You *can* do that - but then the static checker has almost no information to work with to make sure that the invariant remains intact. Where possible it's better to use a set of calls to Contract.Invariant.

Comment: @Jon I see. Well, traditionally the invariant was not statically checked, only called before and after any public function when running with assertion checking on. I understand that Code Contracts try to introduce static analysis value. I still have to learn how that works in practice, though.